# Radio Button Validation (asp.net)

Tags: asp.net

I am working on asp.net where I have few individual radio buttons with group name `Plant Height`, but not as a `radiobuttonlist` and at the bottom there is a button.

When the button is clicked, it should validate that a radio button is checked or else should show the error message.

I know I can create a `radiobuttonlist` and use `requiredfieldvalidator` but I want help with individual radio button with common group name.
[Code here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zFlAz.png)

Comment: Instead of linking to an image of your code, include it in the question and format it as code. It will look a lot nicer and be easier for someone to answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can trick the engine by adding an **hidden field** which stored the value of your radiobutton group.

Put a **RequiredFieldValidator** on this HiddenField and javascript on each radio button to update HiddenField  value on click and you will have what you want ;-)

```
onclick="document.getElementById('<ID_of_HiddenField>').value = this.value"
```

Don't forget to put ID Static for your HiddenField